# How can I track deprecation warning counts in teamcity builds?

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to scan the build log at the end of each Teamcity build to count the number of deprecation warnings in the build. I don't want this to be a failure condition regardless of how many there are. I'd like to make this number a Teamcity statistic so that I can track it over time.

I'm pretty sure there are ways I could achieve this but they quickly become very hacky. I was hoping Teamcity would provide an option to build a statistic from running `grep -c whatever` over the build log but I can't find anything similar.

Is there an option for analyzing the build log to collect Teamcity build statistics?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is. You can create a [TeamCity plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Developing+TeamCity+Plugins) to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a build step that counts deprecation warinings in the app's log (not the Teamcity build log) and print a teamcity formatted message.

```
grep -c "DEPRECATION" %system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/log/app.log | xargs -I{} echo "##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='deprecationCount' value='{}']"
```